# Get rid of "The Publisher could not be verified. Are you sure you want to run this software"?

Tags: windows-7, dep

Can I stop  "The Publisher could not be verified. Are you sure you want to run this software"? from popuping up when I run an exe? It is really annoying :) Will it require me to completely disable DEP?

(PS I'm running windows 7 32 bit)

Comment: I think you mean UAC instead of DEP.  DEP is Data Execution Prevention which helps prevent buffer overflows and other regular data from running as code.  UAC is User Account Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable this dialogue box for ALL .exe files, you can add the following key to your registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations]
"LowRiskFileTypes"=".exe
```

Note: this is not advisable, as it opens up your computer to other risks.

Other than that, **[ClickOff](http://www.johanneshuebner.com/en/clickoff.shtml)** is your friend (a more general approach to such annoyances :)

> ClickOff has been written out of a
>   personal need - like most programs
>   here. Questions like "are you sure
>   you want to exit the program?" made me
>   go insane after having seen them a
>   dozen of times.
>
> ClickOff is developed to be the Swiss
>   Army knife for window handling, not
>   just a simple popup blocker.

Here are some key features:

- Automatically clicks button on error messages that come up all the time.
- Intuitive user interface.
- Closes browser popups
- Minimizes or maximizes windows
- Delay times can be set to allow user intervention
- Single buttons can be disabled temporarily
- False clicks are avoided by taking the message text into the proccess of detecting.
- To close windows that contain certain words, wildcards can be used
- The scanning speed can be set
- Can be disabled for a short period or permanently without having to be exited.
- Has very low system resource needs, takes about 1 sec. to load and doesn't slow down the system while running.

[image]

[image]

*ClickOff is freeware.*

Answer (score 2):

When I download an EXE from the internet, it prompts me as you indicate.  However, if I put an EXE on the desktop (for example) and run it, there's a checkbox that allows me to say "don't prompt me for this again".  You might not get additional checkbox if you're running the program out of the program files directory.  In this case, I believe you can turn off UAC, reboot, run the program, set the checkbox, and then turn back on UAC.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to delete the alternative file stream [Zone.Identifier](https://superuser.com/questions/323933/how-does-windows-security-warning-do-you-want-to-run-this-file-work). This allows you to disable it from a particular .exe

Comment: More details about the streams can be found in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/323942/117908).

Comment: This. Eliminates the root of the problem, rather than causing collateral damage or requiring some kind of kludge, as the accepted answer does. This should be getting more upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

If the EXE was extracted from a ZIP file downloaded from the Internet, do **not** use zipped folders (the File Explorer interface) but a third-party tool such as 7-Zip. (If you have already extracted the EXE and still have the ZIP file, you can simply delete the EXE and extract it again.)

Zipped Folders will preserve the Zone.Identifier ADS (which stores this information), 7-Zip (as of 16.04) will not.