# Windows 7 - Do you want to open this file? Terminate with extreme prejudice

Tags: windows-7, windows, security-policy

Windows 7 asks me that question every time I go to do anything with a file I downloaded from the net. Is there a way to disable that annoying popup for all files, new and old, for all times, no exceptions? I have been clicking on that accursed box for decades, and I have never once clicked no. I do not want to see that popup again, ever. Not for files I just downloaded, not for files I downloaded long ago.

Near duplicate: [How can I disable the "Open File Security Warning" when I want to run downloaded executable files?](https://superuser.com/questions/324954/how-can-i-disable-the-open-file-security-warning-when-i-want-to-run-downloaded)

Edit ... The following has useful info: [How does Windows' security warning "do you want to run this file.." work?](https://superuser.com/questions/323933/how-does-windows-security-warning-do-you-want-to-run-this-file-work)

Edit 2 ... After pouring over the links above, and links they point to, I have discovered how to stop the rot.  Watch this space.